# How to check Compute Engine User Activity Logs?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud, gcloud

Background: I have 50 VMs running across multiple projects in GCP Organization. There are chances that 10 out of them are idle. I want to create a script to filter out the idle VMs that has no crons running or any application running inside. There could be OS-level updates, but we can ignore them.

I have tried installing Ops Agent, I could see certain logs but I am not able to differentiate whether it is OS related logs or user activity/application logs. I am trying to automate this process as there could be more than 200 -300 VMs in future. Also, I have tried using the logName filter in  Logging but still can't differentiate the logs. I don't want to enable Data Access Logs for this purpose, as this can lead to high billing due to storage costs.

Comment: My guess is that we need to be more specific on what constitutes an "idle" VM.  For example (and these are just notions) ... average CPU over the last 5 minutes, presence (or absence) of a named running process, existence/lack of existence of a file.   Also, how are these compute engines started?  Do you want to shut them down from inside the Compute Engine or from outside?

Comment: Can the metrics (CPU usage over 1 day for instance) inform you about the idle state of the VM?